# Configuring Teams Channel with AD Security Group

Tags: microsoft-teams, ad

I have a Sharepoint site with an associated Team configured.
Within the Team, I have a number of Channels.

If I navigate to the SharePoint permissions settings page, I can go to "Advanced permissions settings", and from there add a MS AD Security Group, rather than named individuals (we have existing processes which ensure that the AD group is regularly maintained and updated).

This approach appears to work for the main Teams, but I cannot figure out how to use the same approach for an individual channel. Any attempt to add the AD group via Teams fails, and whilst I can add the AD Group via SharePoint for the main Teams site, I cannot do it for any of the Channels (menu option not available, with a message to administer via Teams).

I've tried adding the AD Group directly; also creating a SharePoint Group, adding the AD Group to that, and referencing the SharePoint group.

I've tried using both private channels, and shared channels.

I'm not going to be able to attempt to create multiple Teams. Since we started using this approach, the number has rocketed and I'm not going to be able to request the creation of another dozen Teams, all with essentially the same function, but serving different AD Groups (which must be separated for IG reasons).

How do I use the AD group please to control access?